# Windows 7 IIS FTP issue

Tags: iis, windows-7, ftp

I've been trying to set up a ftp server using IIS from windows 7. I've been succesfull on my local network but now I want to make it public. I portforwarded port 21, but now when I open up my ftp server externally (ftp://myexternalip) I do get prompted for a username and password, but when I log in I get this log:

```
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,178,14,57,219).
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Consequently I get to see none of the data/files in my ftp server.. I've got no clue what the issue is here nor how to solve this. I'm also certain that my firewall isn't blocking the ftp server, because I turned it off. Anyone with more knowledge that can enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP protocol is different to other protocols, in that it uses not only a dedicated port (21) over which the commands go (this is why you can login etc.) but uses spontaneous other ports for the transmission of the data payload.

This was not a problem, when FTP was designed and client and server typically saw themself directly (and firewalls were exotic), but NAT changes the game: The address your server sees (192.168.178.14) is not visible from the internet.

The only way to fix it is on the NAT: A connection tracking module there will actually intercept and manipulate the command channel to translate NATed addresses/ports into public addresses/ports. Most firewall appliances know how to do this.

In your firewall look for "trigger applications" or "FTP forwarding".

Comment: @user1534664 NAT actually has to rewrite the FTP control packets so that you think that the NAT router is the FTP server.

Comment: @Neil Yes, but isn't this the concept behind portforwarding? Dont I portforward to tell the NAT to what PC the data must be sent to? I portforwarded port 21..

Comment: @user1534664 Normally NAT only changes the IP addresses (and sometimes port numbers) of the packets. It's only for FTP that it has to change the "data" of the packets (actually the FTP commands and/or responses).

Comment: oooo thanks neil! I get what eugen means now. But I dont see any trigger applications or ftp forwarding in my router. Now what? Also, I tried opening up all my ports on my PC (by using DMZ) and it works now, but this is probably not the way to go.

Comment: What sort of firewall do you use? Opening all ports to a windows server seems a bit ... risky to me!

Comment: It is risky ;) I am using windows firewall which I turned off just to make sure it isn't interfering and my router has a built in firewall in which I portforwarded port 21. The ftp server only seems to work when I enable my PC as DMZ host.

Comment: That's what I ment: Which brand/model of router/firewall-combo do you use (this is where the NAT happens) ... I know quite a lot of them and might just know where to look.

Comment: Apparently its a ubee evw3200

Comment: Look into Gateway->Advanced->Port Triggering and set up a range of ports for your Machine: Trigger port=20-21, Target port wahtever you like (e.g. 5000-6000) protocol TCP. Now configure your FTP server to use the same range (e.g. 5000-6000), see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555022/en-us or http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/309/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7/#Step1 HTH

Comment: Thanks dude, it worked for me!! How come port triggering solved the problem, though?

Comment: It works this way: Traffic on the command channel (Port 20, "trigger range") is seen "passing" in the router, instructs the router to route traffic from the same outside IP with a port in the "target range" to the same inside IP as in the "trigger range". So basically the command channel is set up to synamically open the door for port of the data channel.